# Multiple time-critical background tasks

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, so I need some guidance as to which would be the simplest and/or elegant solution to the following problem:

I'm working on a project which has a table with as many as 500,000 records, at user specified periods, a background task must be started which will invoke a command line application on the server that does the magic, the problem is, at each 1 minute or so, I need to check on all 500,000 records(and counting) if something needs to be done.

As the title says, it is time-critical, this means that a maximum of 1 minute delay can be allowed between the time expected by the user and the time that the task is executed, of course the less delay, the better.

Thus far, I can only think of a very dirty option, have a simple utility app that runs on the server, that at each minute, will make multiple requests to the server, example:

- check records between 1 and 100,000;
- check records between 100,000 and 200,000;
- etc. you get the point;

and the server basically starts a task for each bulk of 100,000 records or less, but it seems to me that there must be a faster approach, something similar to facebook's notification.

Additional info:

- server is Windows 2008
- using apache + php

***EDIT 1***

- users have an average of 3 tasks per day at about 6-8 hours interval
- more than half of the tasks can be at least 1 time per day executed at the same time[!]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Usually the approach is to check if a previous task is running and then either kill that task or not start a new one so it has more time to finish. It depends on what you actually need: the same task not running twice under any circumstances / the task being run every minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I gave this question more than enough time, I will stick to a utility application(that sits on the server) that will make requests to a URL accessible only from the server's IP which will spawn a new thread for each task if multiple tasks needs to be executed at the same time, it's not really scalable but it will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach would be using a persistent task that runs the whole time and receives notification about records that need to be processed. Then it could process them immediately or, in case it needs to be processed at a certain time, it could sleep until either that time is reached or another notification arrives.

Comment: +1 thank you for your comment, I just remembered that I've left out an important piece of information, can you please see "Edit 1" and edit your answer please?